# Save data advice C#

Tags: c#, load, save

I have two applications that have clients, the clients on application `A` may have different names than the application `B`. I'm receiving an Excel with data from application `B` that comes with the client name on one of the columns. This Excel can have hundreds of thousands of lines...

I need to check if the client `B` exists on `A`, and if not, i have to create it. Now, on `B` were identified several clients that should represent the same client on `A` (I can´t change B, if I could I would remove "duplicates") but not always the name that client `B` has, should be the same in `A`. With this in mind, there's Excel to map Client `A` to client `B` (even if client A is not in A).

Example:

```
| Client A Name | Client B Name 1 | Client B Name 2 | Etc

| Client 1      | Client asd      |                 |    

| Client 2      |                 |                 |

| Client 3      | Client fgh      | Client 123      |
```

This mapping is supposed to grow, I would say it is not supposed to changed the existing data, but I can never be sure, and so far it has 6234 lines, 12095 cells with data.

I would like to know the best way to deal with this amount of data in order to process the client.

Ideas i have:

1) Load the Excel into a BD table

Good Things:

- BD are the best way to save data (right?)
- Easy way to load the saved data with one select
- Easy to implement CRUD

Bad Things:

- My company has very bureaucratic stuff... to install in QA and PRD i have to go through 2 teams and sometimes wait more than a week per environment and since this development can still change its requirements and business logic i'm trying to escape this...
- No matter what gui i make people will always use excel to change the mapping and they prefer to keep it that way...

2) Load the mapping to memory everytime i need to run this process

Good things:

- No connections to the BD asking for the data and to save, so no need for CRUD
- One less layer involved

Bad Things:

- Slower
- not dry, since I would repeat a somewhat unnecessary load process every run

3) Load the data from the excel to pc once and everytime the excel changes

- Not sure how this would work out... would it be like creating a local txt/csv file?

I saw some examples like:

JSON: [Best way to store data locally in .NET (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941928/best-way-to-store-data-locally-in-net-c)
LocalDB: [What is the best way to store data in c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280555/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-data-in-c-sharp-application)

XML/Binary serialization

Others?

**Notes**

For now it is only planned to load the program one time per week, but this can change to once per day, so i would say option 2 is out.

I intend on having the mapping data in c# dictionaries so search can be faster. My idea would be to a a first dictionary for every letter in the alphabet and the insert another dictionary for each client map.

Example

```
dictionary1

| Key | Value       |

| A   | dictionaryA |

| B   | dictionaryB |

etc
```

On each `dictionary[LETTER]` (depending of the first letter of the client `B` name)

```
| Key        | Value    |

| Client asd | Client 1 |

| Client fgh | Client 3 |

| Client 123 | Client 3 |
```

Comment: Epic. Instead I'd start thinking how to get rid of that mess for good.

Comment: Is all this going in one direction or does it need to go back and forth?

Comment: Hi @MikkoViitala, You are more than right. For me, the ideal would be to integrate application A with B, but no one is going to work on behalf of B and I have no access to it or its data to create the the integration, so I don't any other way right now.

Comment: @Michael_B, what do you mean by "back and forth"? The direction is Excel (that has B's application data)-> Apliccation A

Comment: Does the data from Application A need to be known by Application B? and vise versa...If it's one way I'd approach it in the way you mentioned, but this is a difficult problem. It does not sit well with me to have such a 'fuzzy' connection, you'll spend a lot of time policing it and worrying about if it's working like it should.

Comment: Hi @Michael_B. Application B does not need to know about A. I understand your concern... it has been mine too for quite some time :(. What i'll do is validate everything I can and pass the "hot potato" to the right people. Thx everyone, i guess there is no good solution for this...