# High performance large text storage solution

Tags: sql-server, database, nosql, storage, large-text

Here is the scenario:

1) All the data currently is stored in SQL Server

2) There is one table X that stores the most important and highly accessed data

3) Each record in the table X has one column Y that stores up to 2GB of text

4) Number of records is growing (> 10 million and growing)

5) The column Y with max of 2GB of text per row takes about 90% of space of table X

Problem: database becomes unmanageable and we need to **store data from Column Y somewhere else** (outside of SQL Server)

Question:

**What is the best solutions for storing large text?**

I am looking for a solutions with **least amount of overhead**:

- fast reads
- fast writes
- scalable
- can handle concurrency well

I don't care about full text index or any extra overhead. Just plain storage and access.

PS

Some ideas that I have so far:

- very simple NOSQL database
- flat file - based database
- custom solution that I can write from scratch using some library

Comment: have you looked at filestream or filetable

Comment: I have looked at filestream and filetable. But I am looking for something completely independent of SQL Server

Comment: If the average record size is > 10MB, plain files are probably the best solution. However, design a good directory structure / hierarchy, as windows has problems with lots of files in a single directory.

Comment: I was thinking about plain files, and even combining several records into one plain file because windows does not like lots of files. Is there a super-fast simple database that can read/write from/to plain text files? Or maybe there is a set of libraries that can help? Most importantly it needs to scale out and be perfromant

Comment: average size of files varies. But most importantly numbers of records is hight enought that table X grows to Terrabytes

Answer (score 2):

From what I read about NoSQL technologies, Riak may be a great fit, however, there's certainly overhead with this.  Flat files sound promising, but highly OS and patch dependent - you don't want to be stuck explaining to a customer that Windows Updates caused performance problems.

Comment: Do you have any experience with flat files storage technologies

Comment: Here's a similar discussion, however your size requirements are on a different scale.  Still, most of the responses in this thread are relevant.  [Local Storage in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941928/best-way-to-store-data-locally-in-net-c)