# Permanent Store DATA at client side using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, cookies, web-sql

I'm currently doing a `POS`(`Point of SALE`) project by using `ASP.Net`. My web application works well when `INTERNET` is available to the client, but I'm trying to facilitate the client to use this web application even if the client doesn't have`INTERNET` connectivity.

> So, the tasks on which I did RND are:
>
> 1. Launch Offline version of my web application, by creating a cache manifest file in `HTML5`. So, client can get offline access to the web
>      application when he has no internet connectivity (using
>      `CACHE.APPCACHE`)
> 2. Using `HTML5 WebSql` to store sale-data at client side, when internet is not available at client side. And after that, this offline
>      sale data(Local Sale Data) is synced to the live-database, when
>      internet is connected.

But the issue is this, `HTML5 Web Sql` can be deleted by **"deleting the Cookies and Content data"** in browser. So, all the `sale-data`, from Local Storage, can be deleted. 
Is there any other solution to store data at client side, so that Local Stored data can't be deleted by **"deleting the Cookies and Content data"** in browser.
Or can we store the `LOCAL-Data` into some kind of `XML` file instead of `HTML5 WebSql`!

- `Sale-Data` = Data Storing when making a sale using `POS`
- `Local Storage` = Data storing at client side
- `Live Storage` = Data Storing in Live DataBase

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data in xml file or text file when internet is not available and store that data to your data base when internet became available. hence your data will be safe rather than using cookie because cookie can be deleted.

Comment: Thank You @Natin. But I required some kind of updation in Localy Stored Data, and the major issue with the TEXT-File is to make CRUD operations on it.
Now I'm looking for some `XML-Based` solution

Comment: can we use a json  based solution [Nitin Kumar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6720983/nitin-kumar) instead of xml ??

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Nitin, saving Sale Data in XML file is a better way, and later you can push these data to your Live Storage. And even CRUD operation is easy on XML files.
For more detail information, you can follow the below link-
[Best way to store data locally in .NET (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941928/best-way-to-store-data-locally-in-net-c)

Thanks